# Drupal: Problem with installing Drupal6

Tags: drupal-6

Hi i am new to Drupal. I am trying to install drupal6 with my sql5. and have followed all the necessary steps. i have created a database and given the necessary privileges. However when i try to install drupal the site does not go further from "set up database" to "install site" . i do not get any error. The page just refreshes and does no further action. 
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already tried scouring the Drupal website. My friend has had a problem with setting up Drupal (he couldn't get past "set up database"), and this page solved it: [Database setup fails to proceed. No error. (Drupal 6)](http://drupal.org/node/332730)